# How to Detect when sever communication is down in Vaadin application

Tags: vaadin7

I want to lock the current ui of the server when communication is down. It will be unlocked when the server communication is established again. But i wasn't able to find a way to detect the server status when communication is down (eg when network cable is unplugged). is there a way to do that. any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().addFunction("isOnline", new JavaScriptFunction() {
                @Override
                public void call(JSONArray arguments) throws JSONException, org.json.JSONException {
                    try {
                        String message = arguments.getString(0);
                        Notification.show("Message: " + message);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Notification.show("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });

    Link link = new Link( "Send Message", new ExternalResource( "javascript:isOnline(navigator.onLine)"));
    this.addComponent(link);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to the code. How does it work?